# ValidationError: missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.v1.DeploymentSpec

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-sawtooth

I've created Hyper-V machine and tried to deploy Sawtooth on Minikube using Sawtooth YAML file :
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/master/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-kubernetes-default.yaml

I changed the apiVersion i.e. `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` to  `apiVersion: apps/v1`, though I have launched Minikube in Kubernetes v1.17.0 using this command

> minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.17.0

After that I can't deploy the server. Command is

> kubectl apply -f sawtooth-kubernetes-default.yaml --validate=false

It shows an error with "sawtooth-0" is invalid.

[image]

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: List

items:

- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: sawtooth-0
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: sawtooth-0
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: sawtooth-0
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: sawtooth-devmode-engine
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust:chime
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "devmode-engine-rust -C tcp://$HOSTNAME:5050"

          - name: sawtooth-settings-tp
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "settings-tp -vv -C tcp://$HOSTNAME:4004"

          - name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:chime
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "intkey-tp-python -vv -C tcp://$HOSTNAME:4004"

          - name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:chime
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://$HOSTNAME:4004"

          - name: sawtooth-validator
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
            ports:
              - name: tp
                containerPort: 4004
              - name: consensus
                containerPort: 5050
              - name: validators
                containerPort: 8800
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "sawadm keygen \
              && sawtooth keygen my_key \
              && sawset genesis -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv \
              && sawset proposal create \
                -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv \
                sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=Devmode \
                sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=0.1 \
                -o config.batch \
              && sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch \
              && sawtooth-validator -vv \
                  --endpoint tcp://$SAWTOOTH_0_SERVICE_HOST:8800 \
                  --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
                  --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
                  --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800"

          - name: sawtooth-rest-api
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
            ports:
              - name: api
                containerPort: 8008
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "sawtooth-rest-api -C tcp://$HOSTNAME:4004"

          - name: sawtooth-shell
            image: hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:chime
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - -c
              - "sawtooth keygen && tail -f /dev/null"

- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: sawtooth-0
  spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
      name: sawtooth-0
    ports:
      - name: "4004"
        protocol: TCP
        port: 4004
        targetPort: 4004
      - name: "5050"
        protocol: TCP
        port: 5050
        targetPort: 5050
      - name: "8008"
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8008
        targetPort: 8008
      - name: "8800"
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8800
        targetPort: 8800
```

Comment: What's behind that "enter image description here" link?  Usually I'd expect to see some sort of textual error message; can you replace the link with the actual text of the error you're getting (not an image), and can you include enough of the actual YAML file (not a link) to demonstrate the error?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to fix your deployment `yaml` file. As you can see from your error message, the `Deployment.spec.selector` field can't be empty.

Update the `yaml` (i.e. add `spec.selector`) as shown in below:

```yaml
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: sawtooth-0
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: sawtooth-0
```

- Why `selector` field is important?

The `selector` field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage. In this case, you simply select a label that is defined in the Pod template (`app.kubernetes.io/name: sawtooth-0`). However, more sophisticated selection rules are possible, as long as the Pod template itself satisfies the rule.

- [Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)

**Update:**

The `apiVersion` for k8s service is `v1`:

```yaml
- apiVersion: v1 # Update here
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sawtooth-0
  spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: sawtooth-0
    ... ... ...
```

Comment: I did added selector in deployement and started the minikube machine, now the error is in service.
this is the message I'm getting.....................

```

C:\Users\Debo>minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

C:\Users\Debo>kubectl apply -f sawtooth-kubernetes-default.yaml --validate=false
deployment.apps/sawtooth-0 created
unable to recognize no matches for kind "Service" in version "apps/v1"

```

Comment: @debokarmakar Can you add the updated yaml to the question body, and the result of `kubectl version --short` command after starting minikube?

Comment: C:\Users\Debo>kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.17.0
Server Version: v1.17.0


and yaml file I've updated in the question

Comment: @debokarmakar, I've updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: @debokarmakar WC, Accept the answer, this will be more appreciable 

Comment: About "app.kubernetes.io/name" does it means different vendors support different names?

Comment: @ZufarMuhamadeev see the [recommended](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/#labels) labels, but it can be anything.

Comment: as for now (2021-04), the official tutorial about k8s part is outdated, current k8s version is v1.20.2, I runs it with docker driver on my Arch Linux. My usable yaml file can be found here, it made for u'all. Be sure to modify the volume path for persistent storage path and run `minikube mount src:dest`  first if you runs with docker driver.    https://gist.github.com/kmahyyg/6b5eb6554e3dc15cc751a668ef62f4ec

Answer (score 2):

For api version v1 (and also for apps/v1) you need to use `app: <your lable>`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sawtooth-0
spec:
  selector:
    app: sawtooth-0
```

See : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Does not work. Error: unknown field "app" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector;

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is already covered by @Kamol

---

Some general possible reasons if you are still getting the error :

```
missing required field “XXX” in YYY
```

1. Check `apiVersion` at the top of file (for Deployment, version is: **apps/v1**
   & for service it's **v1**
2. Check the `spelling` of "XXX"*(unknown field)* and check if `syntax` is incorrect.
3. Check `kind: ...` once again.

If you find some other reason, please comment and let other's know :)