# Getting ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec

Tags: kubernetes

I intially referred to similar question here: [ValidationError: missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.v1.DeploymentSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480373)

I changed the apiVersion i.e. apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 to  apiVersion: apps/v1, I am using kubeadm and 3 nodes running workers.

However in my yaml I do have matching label selecters

```
    labels:
      app: rabbitmq
      role: master
      tier: queue
```

and if I try to run the below yaml deployment : I get

The Deployment "rabbitmq" is invalid:

- spec.selector: Required value
- spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"app":"rabbitmq", "role":"master", "tier":"queue"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`

**rabbitmq.yaml**

```
---
# EXPORT SERVICE INTERFACE
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: message-queue
    labels:
      app: rabbitmq
      role: master
      tier: queue
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
      app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
    role: master
    tier: queue
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         app: rabbitmq
         role: master
         tier: queue
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: bitnami-rabbitmq-config
        ports:
        - name: queue
          containerPort: 5672
        - name: queue-mgmt
          containerPort: 15672
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - rabbitmqctl
            - status
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 6
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - rabbitmqctl
            - status
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-storage
          mountPath: /bitnami
      volumes:
      - name: rabbitmq-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: rabbitmq-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `selector:` field under `Deployment.spec`. Currently you only have `replicas:` and `template:` there.

Example from [Deployment docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    ...
```

Also see the format with:

```
kubectl explain Deployment.spec
```